# Google Cloud Storage: Disable permission inheritance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-iam

I have a Google Cloud organisation which gives certain access based on the organisation/folder. For example, a CST staff might get "Storage Object Viewer" on the customer folder to be able to read the cloud storage files for debugging. Each customer is one project in the customer folder.

Now I'm trying to setup a bucket (inside the same project under the customer folder) that only a very selected handful should have access to. Is this possible?

Running `gsutil iam get` shows only 1 service account with access and 1 group, but looking at the UI also all the inherited permissions give read access.

Is there a way (I'm using unified bucket permissions) to disable so there is no inheritance?

Regards,
Niklas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a preview feature named [Deny Policies](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/deny-overview)