# Is it possible to deny access to a Google Storage bucket to all users/service accounts except for specific few?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-iam

I have a Google Storage bucket created via terraform. This bucket has a number of service accounts and user groups that are allowed to view/edit the objects via inherited project permissions. Some of them are coming from GCP services' SAs, such as cloud build.

Based on what I see in the console, I cannot remove inherited permissions.

Using IAM to provide exact access to the bucket to specific service accounts, doesn't remove or prevent the access from all the inherited groups/service accounts.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74359172/google-cloud-storage-disable-permission-inheritance) SO Q&A, I found out about deny polices, which might be something that I'm looking for, but I can't find an example of how to implement it in a way that will be specific to this one bucket.

What is the way in GCP to allow specific read or write access per specific user/service account and no one else?

Comment: Put a tag on the bucket and then use a deny policy matching (`resource.matchTag`) that tag's value. https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-attribute-reference